# Apply function to a column of DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function, replace

How can you apply a function to a certain column of a DF?
I want to apply function replace() to one column of a DF.

I tried following one, but I don't get the desired output

```py
df['DMAge']=df['DMAge'].replace("\n"," ")
```

output:

```py
                              51\n49\n49\n59
     61\n61\n61\n \n49\n \n62\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \...
                                               58\n59
    83\n83\n54\n54\n54\n69\n63\n63\n63\n \n \n59\n...
    48\n48\n48\n68\n \n67\n63\n71\n \n \n62\n \n67...
                                       57\n49\n52\n48
                                            50\n \n39
    47\n47\n50\n50\n50\n \n61\n66\n66\n \n49\n57\n...
                        42\n \n47\n47\n59\n50\n57\n48
                                               55\n54
```

As you see '\n' is still visible

Answer (score 1):

You are almost on the right track. What you need, in my opinion, is adding `regex` attribute to the `replace` function.

```py
df['DMAge']=df['DMAge'].replace("\n"," ", regex=True)
```